# Flash AIR ServiceMonitor Shim.swc

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, air

Does anyone know where I can get a copy of the ServiceMonitorShim.swc for Flash CS5.5?

I am currently running Flash CS5.5 but I don't have the component in my component window.

Thanks,

Mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this in case anyone is looking for the same thing.

http://code.google.com/p/poliwar/source/browse/trunk/projeto/servidor/lib/air2b2/?r=66